# Adding child node to XML variable - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, xml, simplexml

I am trying to populate the values of a SOAP request that needs to be sent using php curl. I have setup a variable with the soap.xml request and have gotten all the data that's needed to be passed.

```
$shipBody = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:v1="http://servicescom/ws/merchantAPI/v1.0">
      <soap:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-1.xsd">
          <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username>'.$username.'</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password>'.$password.'</wsse:Password>
          </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
      </soap:Header>
      <soap:Body>
        <v1:parcelShipmentNotification>
          <parcel>
            <carrierName>'.$carrierName.'</carrierName>
            <carrierService>'.$carrierService.'</carrierService>
            '.$xml_data->children('itemdatastring')->asXML().'<!--Tried adding data as children but didn't return anything-->
            '.$xml_data->asXML().'<!--This worked but i couldn't remove the extra "itemdatastring"-->
            <orderId>'.$exId.'</orderId>
            <parcelId>'.$parcelId.'</parcelId>
            <parcelReference>'.$shipDate.'</parcelReference>
            <shippingDate>'.$shipDate.'</shippingDate>
            <trackingURL>https://tools.usps.com/go/TrackConfirmAction?tLabels='.$trackingUrl.'</trackingURL>
          </parcel>
          <requestPackingSlip>true</requestPackingSlip>
        </v1:parcelShipmentNotification>
      </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>';
```

I am able to create a function to get all line items with sku and qty but i am having difficulties passing the return value into the $shipBody variable. Here is a sample line items;

```
$myShipment = array ( 
array(
    'sku' => 'BA2222222',
    'qty' => '2'
    ),
array(
    'sku' => 'BA111111',
    'qty' => '4'
    ),
);
```

Here is how i'm am currently getting the XML for line items.

```
function array_to_xml( $dataToConvert, $xml_data ) {
    foreach( $dataToConvert as $key => $value ) {
        if( is_numeric($key) ){
            $key = 'items'; //dealing with <0/>..<n/> issues
        }
        if( is_array($value) ) {
            $subnode = $xml_data->addChild($key);
            array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
        } else {
            $xml_data->addChild("$key",htmlspecialchars("$value"));
        }
     }
}

$orderLineItems = array();
foreach ($myShipment as $orderItem) {
    $orderItemSku = $orderItem['sku'];
    $orderItemQty = $orderItem['qty'];

    $orderLineItems[] = array(
      'quantity' => $orderItemQty,
      'sku' => $orderItemSku
    );
}

$xml_data = new SimpleXMLElement('<itemdatastring></itemdatastring>');
array_to_xml($orderLineItems,$xml_data);
```

And Finally, Here is what the finished file should look like;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:v1="http://servicescom/ws/merchantAPI/v1.0">
  <soap:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-1.xsd">
      <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username>'.$username.'</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password>'.$password.'</wsse:Password>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <v1:parcelShipmentNotification>
      <parcel>
        <carrierName>'.$carrierName.'</carrierName>
        <carrierService>'.$carrierService.'</carrierService>
        <items>
            <quantity>2</quantity>
            <sku>BA2222222</sku>
        </items>
        <items>
            <quantity>4</quantity>
            <sku>BA111111</sku>
        </items>
        <orderId>'.$exId.'</orderId>
        <parcelId>'.$parcelId.'</parcelId>
        <parcelReference>'.$shipDate.'</parcelReference>
        <shippingDate>'.$shipDate.'</shippingDate>
        <trackingURL>https://tools.usps.com/go/TrackConfirmAction?tLabels='.$trackingUrl.'</trackingURL>
      </parcel>
      <requestPackingSlip>true</requestPackingSlip>
    </v1:parcelShipmentNotification>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Any help/pointers will be really appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Could you [edit] to simplify the example a bit? There's a lot of extra XML here that I think is not really relevant to the problem - try to reduce it to a [mcve], even if that means making up your own XML document with lots of `<foo>` and `<example>` in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `->children()`, you get a list of nodes back, so trying to call `$xml_data->children('itemdatastring')->asXML()` will fail.

You can do something like...

```
$itemString = '';
foreach ( $xml_data->children() as $item ) {
    $itemString .= $item->asXML();
}
```

Which will build up a string from each individual element and then use `$itemString` in your XML.

Comment: Note that the argument you've passed as `'itemdatastring'` here will be interpreted as a namespace URI. I think what you actually wanted here was child elements named `<itemdatastring>` which would just be `foreach ( $xml_data->itemdatastring as $item )`.

Comment: The problem with copying OP's code and not being awake enough to actually read it :-/  Corrected - thanks.